# How do you make grunt.js not crash on warnings by default?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using Grunt to compile CoffeeScript and Stylus with a watch task. I also have my editor (SublimeText) set to save files every time I page away from them (I hate losing work).

Unfortunately, if Grunt hits a syntax error in any of the files it's compiling, it throws a warning and quits with `Aborted due to warnings`. I can stop it doing this by passing `--force`. Is there any way to make not aborting the default behavior (or control which tasks' warnings are important enough to quit Grunt?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Register your own task, which will run the tasks you want. Then you have to pass the `force` option:

```
grunt.registerTask('myTask', 'runs my tasks', function () {
    var tasks = ['task1', ..., 'watch'];

    // Use the force option for all tasks declared in the previous line
    grunt.option('force', true);
    grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```

Comment: This works but then the force option is on for all remaining tasks in the sequence. I have another hack in an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612495/continue-certain-tasks-in-grunt-even-if-one-fails/16972894#16972894)

Comment: Couldn't you just do grunt.option('force', false); after running the tasks?

Answer (score 3):

I tried [asgoth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15448265/3188412)'s solution with [Adam Hutchinson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423851/how-do-you-make-grunt-js-not-crash-on-warnings-by-default#comment36109339_15448265)'s suggestion, but found that the force flag was being set back immediately to false. Reading the [grunt.task](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task) API docs for grunt.task.run, it states that

> Every specified task in taskList will be run immediately after the current task completes, in the order specified.

Which meant that I couldn't simply set the force flag back to false immediately after calling grunt.task.run. The solution I found was to have explicit tasks setting the force flag to false afterwards:

```
grunt.registerTask('task-that-might-fail-wrapper','Runs the task that might fail wrapped around a force wrapper', function() {
    var tasks;
    if ( grunt.option('force') ) {
        tasks = ['task-that-might-fail'];
    } else {
        tasks = ['forceon', 'task-that-might-fail', 'forceoff'];
    }
    grunt.task.run(tasks);
});

grunt.registerTask('forceoff', 'Forces the force flag off', function() {
    grunt.option('force', false);
});

grunt.registerTask('forceon', 'Forces the force flag on', function() {
    grunt.option('force', true);
});
```