# How can I make a Grunt task fail if one of its sub tasks fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jshint

I have a build task in grunt, which looks like this:

```
grunt.registerTask("build", ["jshint", "uglify"]);
```

The problem is that the uglify task runs even if the jshint task fails, how can I make the 'build' task terminate if one of it's sub tasks fails?

Answer (score 3):

The default behavior in Grunt is to not run subsequent tasks if one fails. So you must be using the force option somewhere. You are either:

1 - passing `--force` on the command line

2 - calling `grunt.option( 'force', true );` somewhere

3 - have the [jshint force option](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint#force) set on your jshint task

Note that in the case of calling `grunt.option( 'force', true );`, it remains true for the remainder of the batch, not just inside the task where it was set. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423851/how-do-you-make-grunt-js-not-crash-on-warnings-by-default?lq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612495/continue-certain-tasks-in-grunt-even-if-one-fails/16972894#16972894) for details.